# How should I use Stax2 Validation API against a W3 Schema

Tags: java, xsd, stax, woodstox

I am using **com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory** to generate XML.
I am running wstx-asl-3.2.4

I need to start validating the generated XML against a W3 Schema.

When I create an instance of **org.codehaus.stax2.validation.XMLValidationSchemaFactory** like this

`private final static XMLValidationSchemaFactory xsdFact=
    XMLValidationSchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLValidationSchema.SCHEMA_ID_W3C_SCHEMA);`

I get the error

> javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: No XMLValidationSchemaFactory implementation class specified or accessible (via system property 'org.codehaus.stax2.validation.XMLValidationSchemaFactory.w3c', or service definition under 'META-INF/services/org.codehaus.stax2.validation.XMLValidationSchemaFactory.w3c')
>       at org.codehaus.stax2.validation.XMLValidationSchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLValidationSchemaFactory.java:208)
>       at org.codehaus.stax2.validation.XMLValidationSchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLValidationSchemaFactory.java:98)

I can see that woodstox is bundled with a DTD parser only.
I found [this article](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2006/08/entry_15.html)
which contains the unhelpful instruction

> 1. Get an instance of XMLValidationSchemaFactory that knows how to parse schemas of the type you need (RelaxNG == rng for this example).

I have been looking at the [Sun Multi-Schema XML Validator](https://msv.dev.java.net/) which is supposed to contain the bits necessary to bolt on to the XMLSchemaValidation factory.

It looks like I might be able to use **com.sun.msv.reader.xmlschema.XMLSchemaReader**
to write my own instance of XMLValidationSchemaFactory and get it to work this way.

My question is; do I really have to do this, or is there a pre-existing w3c schema factory that I have failed to find?

Perhaps it would be simpler just to validate the XML *after* I have generated it.

What are the views on this ?

Comment: actually I have just googled for com.ctc.wstx.msv.W3CSchemaFactory. I might just need to upgrade my woodstox version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've upgraded to Woodstox 4.0.8, W3CSchemaFactory comes bundled and its all good.

Comment: Yes; sorry for late response byt XML Schema support was just added in 4.0. 3.2 did support RelaxNG using MSV, as well as native DTD validation, but not yet XML Schema.